# InvalidArgumentException - No hint path defined

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to add controller view in my existing project that consider model view controller structure in php with laravel.

```
class CashFlowdataController extends Controller {
 
    public function index() { 
        return view('CashFlowdata::create');
    }

}
```

When I implement this, it shows me error for,

```
InvalidArgumentException
No hint path defined for [CashFlowdata].
```

I have added file in route.php and web.php as added other controller data. Only for this one it shows message like this.

Comment: so what namespace ('hint') is `CashFlowdata` supposed to represent for the view files? where did you define this view hint (namespace)

Comment: CashFlowData represents controller which supposed to redirect to view filw of create.

Comment: where did you register the view namespace(hint) ? it is something you have to actually setup

Comment: @DaminiSuthar hey can you take a look my answer?

Comment: you are trying to use view helper function but passing a static function syntax in it, I suggest @KamleshPaul should work for you

Answer (score 0):

you code is wrong you should to something like this

```php
class CashFlowdataController extends Controller {
 
    public function index() { 
        return view('CashFlowdata.create');
    }
}
```

here **`CashFlowdata.create`**

its means in laravel

folder structure should be

> view>CashFlowdata>create.blade.php

laravel `view()` function is a helper to load view file
ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-view

Comment: they are using nwidart/laravel-modules i have the same problem.
https://nwidart.com/laravel-modules/v6/basic-usage/custom-namespaces

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in nwidart/laravel-modules due to module.json file was miss place.
I move the file to the root of module now working fine.